# Does this set of calcs require dynamic SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, min

I am having trouble processing the below query in SQL Server Manager 2012. I have been able to do the calculations iteratively, but it uses too much processor time, thus I need to wrap it into a single query. Thanks

```
    CREATE TABLE [Execution Timing4]
    ([Instance] DATETIME, [Date] DATETIME, [Time] TIME, 
    [Ticker] CHAR (20), 
    [Total_Score] REAL, rank REAL, row_number REAL, 
    [Intraday Return] float, 
    [Prior Close] float, [Closing Print] float, 
    [Close to Close Return] float, [Return Differential] float, 
    [Execute Sale] float, [First Sale] time, [Second Sale] time, 
    [Third Sale] time, [Fourth Sale] time, 
    [Number of Sales] float, [Sale Weighted Return] float);

INSERT INTO [Execution Timing4] ([Instance]
      ,[Date]
      ,[Time]
      ,[Ticker]
      ,[Total_Score]
      ,[rank]
      ,[row_number]
      ,[Intraday Return]
      ,[Prior Close]
      ,[Closing Print]
      ,[Close to Close Return]
      ,[Return Differential]
      ,[Execute Sale]
      ,[First Sale]
      ,[Second Sale]
      ,[Third Sale]
      ,[Fourth Sale])
      SELECT [Instance]
      ,[Date]
      ,[Time]
      ,[Ticker]
      ,[Total_Score]
      ,[rank]
      ,[row_number]
      ,[Intraday Return]
      ,[Prior Close]
      ,[Closing Print]
      ,[Close to Close Return]
      ,[Return Differential]
      ,[Execute Sale]
      ,(SELECT MIN(T.[Time]) FROM Scorecard AS T
      WHERE T.[Ticker] = O2.[Ticker] AND T.[Date] = O2.[Date] 
    AND T.[Execute Sale] = '1')
      FROM [Scorecard] AS O2
      ,(SELECT MIN(T.[Time]) FROM Scorecard AS T
      WHERE T.[Ticker] = O3.[Ticker] AND T.[Date] = O3.[Date] 
    AND T.[Execute Sale] = '1' AND T.[Time] > O3.[First Sale] AND T.[Time] > '09:45:00.0000000')
      FROM [Scorecard] AS O3
      ,(SELECT MIN(T.[Time]) FROM Scorecard AS T
      WHERE T.[Ticker] = O4.[Ticker] AND T.[Date] = O4.[Date] 
    AND T.[Execute Sale] = '1' AND T.[Time] > O4.[Second Sale] AND T.[Time] > '11:40:00.0000000')
      FROM [Scorecard] AS O4
      , (SELECT MIN(T.[Time]) FROM Scorecard AS T
      WHERE T.[Ticker] = O5.[Ticker] AND T.[Date] = O5.[Date] 
    AND T.[Execute Sale] = '1' AND T.[Time] > O5.[Third Sale] AND T.[Time] > '13:50:00.0000000')
      FROM [Scorecard] AS O5
```

Comment: This query is a trainwreck. The formatting is so painful it is really hard to decipher. Then you seem to have a number of cross joins between various iterations of queries. I don't understand where dynamic sql fits in here at all. Perhaps if you can share the table, some sample data and an explanation of what your trying to do we can help.

Comment: Sorry for the formatting...

Comment: here is some sample data: (from expected output)

Comment: Instance 1/5/2015 42009.39653
Date 1/5/2015 1/5/2015
Time 0.396527778 0.396527778
Ticker SLB                  MRO                 
Total_Score 3442.054 3386.137
rank 1 2
row_number 1 2
Intraday Return 0.004457652 0.021681248
Prior Close 82.99 27.56
Closing Print 80.76 26.29
Close to Close Return -0.026870707 -0.046081277
Return Differential 0.03132836 0.067762525
Execute Sale 1 1
First Sale 0.396527778 0.396527778
Second Sale 0.454861111 0.451388889
Third Sale NULL 0.489583333
Fourth Sale NULL NULL
Number of Sales 2 3
Sale Weighted Return -0.014456899 -0.007906778

Comment: and the scorecard is very similar. I am trying to specify when stocks are sold, and sometimes only the first 25% or 50% is sold (not all of it).

Comment: Don't add sample data as a comment. It will not format well and as such it is completely useless. Instead post the table definition and insert statements as an edit to your question.

Comment: Holy cow...do you really need so many cartesian joins?